# Как правильно создать галерею на PHP и MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.

Допустим есть Интернет магазин с продуктами на сайте. Нужно создать галерею под выбранный продукт. Будет ли работать следующая схема.?

Например: Есть таблица в БД инфо о продуктах. id, name, price, discription.
Теперь о таблице img_product с 3 полями: id, img_src, id_product. ID понятно, img_src путь к изображению, id_product - id продукта к которому будет относиться данное фото. Т.е. заполненные таблицы будут выглядить так:

**Таблица продукта:**
id - 1;

name - Компьютер;

price - 100 000;

discription - какое то описание продукта

**Таблица изображений**

id - 1;

imgsrc-img/product/1.jpg

id_product - 1;

**Вторая строчка**

id - 2;

imgsrc-img/product/2.jpg

id_product - 1;

Вывод изображений и создание галереи на jquery не интересуют, интересуют на сколько правилен смысле создании такой галерея с хранения всех путей в таблице. Будет ли сильно тупить если будет допустим 1000 или 10 000 товаров.?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура правильная. Для полноты добавьте строку default_image в таблицу продуктов для хранения id изображения по умолчанию.
Я у себя в галлерее добавляю в поле image только имя картинки. Сам путь к изображению формирую /image/$categoryID/$productID/$image.
По поводу поля sort правильно заметили. В таком случае можно не использовать default_image, а брать изображение с sort == 1

Comment: интересует еще вопрос, а в поле imgsrc я должен указывать только путь одного изображения? или нескольких а потом через какой то разделитель выводить их.

Comment: если совсем для полноты, тогда уже лучше поле sort_order в таблицу изображений. не будет ненужных данных в таблице продуктов и остальные можно будет отсортировать

Comment: >в поле imgsrc я должен указывать только путь одного изображения? 

Конечно, одна картинка - одна запись в БД. И путь я бы вообще не хранил, достаточно его конструировать из глобального пути для картинок, ID товара и ID самой картинки. А ситуаций, в которых одна картинка используется для нескольких товаров, лучше избегать (кроме дефолтных картинок, но это уже отдельная история)

Comment: Дополнил ответ